# Generating List of Tags from Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I have created a Custom Post Type "model" with corresponding tags "model_tag". I am trying to generate a list of tags chosen for the post. I am able to generate a string using the code below, however I would like to output it as a list.

```
                            <?php
                            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'model_tag' );
                            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                                $limits_links = array();
                                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                    $limit_links[] = $term->name;
                                }
                                $model_tag = join( ", ", $limit_links );
                            ?>

                            <?php echo $model_tag; ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Seems like you're outputting the terms in a comma-separated list currently. Are you saying you want to list them using something like list items?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity. Looking to ouput as a list that I can style into columns ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is list out the model tags as list items, this should work for you:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'model_tag' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
    $model_tags = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $model_tags .= '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    $model_tags .= '</ul>';

    echo $model_tags; ?>
endif;
```

Comment: Didnt work. After using your code the list of tags are not showing at all.

Comment: Looks like some of the variables got switcheroo-d. I've updated the answer.